# How to extract data from HashMap<String, Object> in Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I have Spring Boot project on backend and Android app on frontend. Communication between the two happens via `Retrofti2`. On one of the endpoits, actually `/login` endpoint, is retruning a `HashMap<String, Object>`. That endpoint looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {

    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("user", getUserObject());
    map.put("token", getJwtToken());

    return  ResponseEntity.ok(map);
}
```

Interface for method call looks like this:

```
public interface LoginService {

    @POST("login")
    Call<HashMap<String, Object>> testLogin(@Body Login login); //login contains username and password strings
}
```

The reposnse in frontend look like this:

```
Call<HashMap<String, Object>> call = mLoginService.testLogin(new Login(username, password));

call.enqueue(new Callback<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<HashMap<String, Object>> call, Response<HashMap<String, Object>> response) {
        if (!response.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        //extract user & token
        HashMap<String, Object> map = response.body();

        Log.i("Test result", map.get("token").toString());
        Log.i("Test result", map.get("user").toString());

        User u = (User) map.get("user");

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome " + u.getUsername()   + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        startActivity(goToEmailsIntent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<HashMap<String, Object>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot login, look at the console", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("ERRROOOOOOR during login", t.toString());
        return;
    }
});
```

When I look at the log statements in the console everything is okey, I get the data which I want. But when trying to cast to User object I get exception.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.example.email.model.User
```

How to get around this? Is there any better way to send User object and a String from backend?

Answer (score 0):

**First method**

When you can change your backend service then modify the backend service return DTO not HashMap.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Token> login(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
    // create your response
    Token token = new Token();

    return  ResponseEntity.ok(token);
}
```

**Second method**

Use json format to exchange data,in your onResponse method you can do like below:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = response.body();
// map.get("user) may return a null value
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(map.get("user));
User user = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,User.class);

// do other thing as you want
```